# error 13 in mysql process, how do I fix this?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I have a website running on my server. The site has been running for a while with no problems.
Now when I go to the URL the page says that there is an error connecting to the database.
to debug I have used ssh to connect to my droplet and run the command: systemctl status mysql.service
That outputs the following:

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2023-04-17 18:18:39 UTC; 39s ago
Docs: man:mysqld(8)
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html
Process: 674 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql-8.0/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 836 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 836 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Status: "Server startup in progress"
Error: 13 (Permission denied)
Apr 17 18:18:35 wordpress-ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-intel-nyc1-01 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Apr 17 18:18:39 wordpress-ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-intel-nyc1-01 mysqld[836]: 2023-04-17T18:18:39.146822Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.26) starting as proces>
Apr 17 18:18:39 wordpress-ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-intel-nyc1-01 mysqld[836]: 2023-04-17T18:18:39.190500Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010187] [Server] Could not open file '/var/log/mysql/error.log' for e>
Apr 17 18:18:39 wordpress-ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-intel-nyc1-01 mysqld[836]: 2023-04-17T18:18:39.192690Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
Apr 17 18:18:39 wordpress-ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-intel-nyc1-01 mysqld[836]: 2023-04-17T18:18:39.203545Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.26)>
Apr 17 18:18:39 wordpress-ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-intel-nyc1-01 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 17 18:18:39 wordpress-ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-intel-nyc1-01 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 17 18:18:39 wordpress-ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-intel-nyc1-01 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

I then checked the error logs for mysql with: sudo less /var/log/mysql/error.log

```
and saw many new errors that repeated these lines:
2023-04-17T16:16:42.385405Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-012592] [InnoDB] Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
2023-04-17T16:16:42.385446Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-012595] [InnoDB] The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to the directory.
2023-04-17T16:16:42.436972Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.26) MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

I think this is a permissions issue for mysql but I do not know where or how to fix it. How would you troubleshoot this?

Comment: `Could not open file '/var/log/mysql/error.log'` seems pretty clear; it doesn't have permission to write to the logs. Make sure the user you're running MySQL as has permission to write to that directory and file.

Comment: @ceejayoz yeah it's pretty clear that it is a permissions issue but I'm not sure what to do about that...

Answer (score 0):

By default, MySQL Server runs as a daemon using the user id `mysql` and group id `mysql`. Files and directories the MySQL Server process uses must have permissions so that user & group can read and write them.

Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-linuxunix-excerpt/8.0/en/data-directory-initialization.html

> Grant directory user and group ownership to the mysql user and mysql
> group, and set the directory permissions appropriately:
>
> ```
> chown mysql:mysql mysql-files
> chmod 750 mysql-files
> ```

That's the step for the data directory, but you should make sure other locations needed by the MySQL Server also exist and are writable by the MySQL Server process.

For example the log directory:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/log/mysql
sudo chown mysql:mysql /var/log/mysql
sudo chmod 750 /var/log/mysql
```

You should read the rest of the page I linked to.